# How to solve the ordinary differential equation $\frac{dv}{v(1 + v^2/c^2)} = \tau_0 \,dt$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Could you assist me to solve this problem?
$$
\frac{dv}{v(1+ v^2/c^2)} = \tau_0dt. \qquad (\tau_0 = 1.5)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is already a separated "differential equation", assuming $c$ is a constant.

Simply integrate each side of the equation.

$$\int \frac{dv}{v(1+ v^2/c^2)} = \int 1.5 dt$$

The right-hand side is straight-forward. In the left hand side, put $u = \dfrac{v^2}{c^2}$.

$$\int \frac{dv}{v(1+ v^2/c^2)} = \int \frac {v\,dv}{v^2(1 + \frac{v^2}{c^2})}$$

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$$\frac1{v(1+ v^2/c^2)}=\frac{2v}{2v^2(1+v^2/c^2)}$$

Set $v^2/c^2=u$ and integrate